# Logging request-response from java service

Tags: java, request, response, wsdl2java

I have generated some proxy classes that are consumed by a Java Service. (using WSDL2JAVA)

I need to find a way to log requests and responses whenever the proxy class invokes the respective external web service.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Thanks!
Silvio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Axis, configure log4j like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR
log4j.appender.axisLogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.axisLogFile.File=soap-messages.log
log4j.appender.axisLogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.axisLogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{DATE} - %-5p] %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender=DEBUG, axisLogFile
```

Answer (score 1):

This is awesome, you need add the following for in java code.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(<log4j property file>);
```